# Get Paragraph to sit next to my image

Tags: html, css

Ive gone through all the other questions regarding this but none of them are helping. my paragraph has a border around it and the border is going through my image while my text does not. 
how do i get my border to to not screw everything up for me?
my code:

```
<div>
   <img src="#"> <h3 class=bio> text text text text </h3>
</div>
```

Css

```
.bio {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 10px solid #f7b733;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  float: left;
  position: fixed, left;
  border: 8px solid #fc4a1a;
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use 2 things to get this done.**

> 1 Use  `display:inline-block` to align them side by side.
>
> 2. Use `vertical-align:middle` to align vertically center w.r.t each other.

Below is a working snippet.

```css
.bio {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 10px solid #f7b733;
  padding: 4px;

  display: inline-block;vertical-align:middle;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 8px solid #fc4a1a; vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="#">
  <h3 class=bio> text text text text </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use flexbox with easier approach, something like this

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
}
.bio {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 10px solid #f7b733;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" >
  <h3 class="bio"> text text text text text text </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Use `display:inline`

```css
  .bio {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 10px solid #f7b733;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
  display: inline;
}

img {
  display: inline;
  border: 8px solid #fc4a1a;
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="#">
  <h3 class=bio> text text text text </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to keep the image and paragraph horizontally..then use flex on the parent div..you can get rid of many styles this way..and there are more options to adjust your children too..You can find more about flex here :[flex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

Please see this Fiddle [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/y23cqp3y/1/)

```css
 .parent {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
   }

.bio {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 10px solid #f7b733;
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
img {
  border: 8px solid #fc4a1a;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="#"> <h3 class=bio> text text text text  text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext</h3>
</div>
```